# A bizarre dance party problem

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

In a dance party $48$ married couples are invited to participate. There are two separate standard card decks. Each man is given a card from the first deck and each woman is given a card from the second deck in such a way that the value of a man's card can not be greater than the value of his wife's card (but can be the same). A man prefers to dance with a woman if her card has the same suit as his wife's card and the value of her(the women) card is greater than his card. But if he can not find one, he prefers to dance with his wife. Prove that a perfect match exists that respects all preferences.

Comment: What does "her card is similar to his wife's card" mean in practical terms?

Comment: Should "is similar to" read "has the same suit as"?

Comment: Yes same suit. I will edit it. It's like both are hearts or spreads but with different value.

Comment: What characterises a perfect match, exactly? Can you clarify on the conditions for a man to dance with another woman? Say a man receives a 5, his wife receives a 3, and two other women a 7 and an 8, all same suit, say; with which woman will he want to dance? (7 I suppose (?))

Comment: "man's card can not be greater than the value of his wife's card" so if a man gets 5, his wife must get 5 or more. In your example the man equally prefers to dance with the woman who got 7 and who got 8 over his wife(considering she got something 5 or more)

Comment: So, a perfect match is one where every man dances with a woman that is not his wife but has a card of the same suit, and every woman has a card greater or equal than their man? A man doesn't care if he dances with a woman with a card less than his or his wife's, right? If so, then what about this: assign the first twelve men to the first (lowest) cards of the first suit. To their wives, assign the same cards as their husbands. Now make the $x$-th husband dance with the wife of the $(x+1)$-th husband, the twelfth dancing with the wife of the first. Repeat for the remaining three dozens of men.

Comment: A perfect match is one where every man dances with a women they prefer to dance with. It can be their wife or other women. If the dance partner is a woman other than wife, her card must have the same suit as his wife's card and the value of her card \textbf{must be greater than his card}. So, he cares about the value and the suit of his dancing partner's card

Comment: Have you learned about Hall's Marriage Theorem? I don't know whether it solves the problem, but it's something I would try.

Comment: Yes, I tried with Hall's Marriage Theorem. Clearly $N(S)$ can not be less than $S$ because husband and wife are always neighbors. But how to work with preferences?

Answer (score 1):

With a slight change to the answer from @wet we have a solution:

Assign the first twelve men to the first (lowest) cards of the first suit. To their wives, assign the same cards as their husbands, *except to the wife of the husband with the card 1, who gets card 13*. Now make the $x$-th husband dance with the wife of the $(x+1)$-th husband, the twelfth dancing with the wife of the first. Repeat for the remaining three dozens of men.